# VS2015 MVC6 References Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have just downloaded VS2015 Community an d have started to use one of the tutorials demonstrating an app using Web API, MVC6, ASPNet5, EF7 and AngularJS. I am not a newbie, jut new to VS2015 and the latest open source .Net.

I couldn't get the app to work and I ended up with "References (Errors = see Error List)". There were no actual errors listed, so I thought I must have messed up so I did the following:

Uninstalled VS2015
Downloaded and reinstalled VS2015 Community.
Opened VS2015 
Created A New Project of type ASP.Net Web Application and Web Applicaation.

Before adding ANY files the References contains a long list of errors (so at least now the errors are listed.

The project was named ContosoBooks and the errors occur in a file called "AccountControllers.cs" which I assume is a generated file. The errors are of the form:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    ContosoBooks.DNX 4.5.1  full path to file

The offending line is:
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication;

I admit to being totally baffled since at this point I have not written a single line of code - it has all been generated from a few mouse clicks. That's why I uninstalled and reinstalled but there must be something else sticking around which is causing it.

Could somone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you install [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442)?

Comment: No, but I am right now. Will report how it goes

Comment: That fixed it. I guess I just assumed that ASP.Net was included.  I will mark as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (Beta8)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442).